# detect create process

Tags: process, driver, detect, antivirus

I 'm writting a litle program can protect computer from malware.So,I want to hook into functions which creates process before it is loaded(before it is loaded,i want to check md5 sum).What can I do ?

Comment: I code in Windows.Can you help me ???

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Vista SP1 or higher you can use ObRegisterCallback routine ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557745(v=vs.85).aspx ). It is available in kernel mode only but I guess you are OK with that as you used the tag "driver".